# How to stop squid from logging some specific URL?

Tags: networking

I have a centOS 7 server with Squid installed as transparent proxy in it and it's doing a great job. The only problem that I am having is that it's keeping log of my CRM as well which generates one request every 3 second and it's so annoying. I want to exclude this particular site. I have only one client computer right now and the log is crowded. Imagine 50-60 computers doing the same thing. How do I do it?

Comment: I tried making an ACL for the website and adding them to always_direct. I also tried "cache deny aclname " but it was no use. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found out that this can be achieved through making some changes to squid.conf file....

to do so make a separate ACL with all the websites that you want to prevent form logging... and add the following to squid.conf file:

`log_access deny safelist`   # where safelist is acl name

## UPDATE

This is now `access_log`

http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/access_log/

Example:

```
acl nolog dstdom_regex "/etc/squid/acl-nolog.txt"
access_log none nolog
access_log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log all
```

A list of acl's can be found at

https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#Fast_and_Slow_ACLs